# Favicon for all the pages in my website

Tags: apache, tomcat, icons, html, favicon

I've learned that the way to add favicon for a web page is to have the following lines in the page.

```
<link rel="SHORTCUT ICON" type="image/x-icon" href="http://mysite.com/faviconfilename.ico"/>
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="http://mysite.com/faviconfilename.ico" />
```

Should i add this code in each and every page my site has?? I use Apache - tomcat clustering to serve pages. Is there any other easy way to do this?

Comment: You don't need two of those lines. The first one is enough (if you lowercase that yelling "SHORTCUT ICON" ;) ).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It is usually enough to place a file called "favicon.ico" in the root of your website.

Answer (score 9):

You can get rid of the unnecessary processing and traffic as well as the error log entries by using the following Apache configuration incantations:

```
# Don't bother looking for favicon.ico
Redirect 404 /favicon.ico

# Send custom text instead of sending the custom error page
<Location /favicon.ico>
    ErrorDocument 404 "No favicon"
</Location>
```

Comment: This is the most strange answer ever :) Why you might want to save traffic from favicon?

Comment: If this file is served from the server then 16kb * 1000 visitors in an hour means 16mb, and we're only talking about 1000 visitors, imagine what happens when you have 100,000 per minute without static hosting.

Comment: Strange: My `favicon.ico` is exactly 302 bytes long. I think today useless JavaScript wastes much more bandwidth than the icon.

Comment: This is really useful when your site is an API that serves only json. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 5):

Modify the apache config.

upload this file to the root directory of your website. Make sure that it is readable so that apache can read it. If you have shell access, type: "chmod +r favicon.ico".

Then edit  httpd.conf and insert the following line:

"AddType image/x-icon .ico"

Your approach works when you don't have access to your apache config. In this case, if you are using any framework then you should add it to your layout/template.

Comment: Can you explain why the execute bit must be set? I feel that might be some obsolete work-around while there should be better methods today.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my method for php sites. It ensures that if you update the favicon, it will be updated immediatly when your clients visit your site:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico?v=<?php echo time() ?>" />
```

Comment: You dont even need the `v=` . You can just have the `favicon.ico?<?php echo time(); ?>`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4248343/why-isnt-my-favicon-showing-up/28290006#28290006

If you use echo time(), you will effectively make the browser download the favicon each page load. That is a waste of bandwidth usage for you and your users. Using a static parameter ?v=1 will allow you to break cache, and will allow the broswer(s) to cache the favicon.