# How can I find out where/how the favicon is included (with access to the site root)

Tags: php, wordpress, favicon

I'm managing a website running on WordPress for one of my clients. I've done most of the setup for the site myself, including the WordPress installation, and somewhere along the way a random favicon has "slipped in". Also, oddly enough, it only shows up when visiting the "root"  of the domain (please enlighten me if there's a more proper term); that is, if you go to one of the subpages the favicon no longer shows up on the tab or in the address bar.

Please have a look at the site [here](http://www.sjalochkropp.se). I have access to the server root where all the files are located, and I have tried searching the entire site directory (and file content) for stuff like "fav", "favicon" and ".ico". There's no link to the favicon in the site `<head>` as far as I can see.

How can I find out where the (link to the) favicon is located so I can remove it? Are there other ways of including a favicon than using `<link>` in the head that I can look into?

[image: favicon]

Comment: I don't see a favicon and I've analyzed the site using privacy tools and no request are done to external servers for icons. If you refresh using `Ctrl+F5`, the favicon will probably disappear.

Comment: I've added a picture of the icon. Tried refreshing several times but it keeps showing up. So strange that you don't see it then!

Comment: You have to clear your browser file cache. Then refresh and look again.

Comment: @SakhalTurkaystan I've cleared the cache (before and now once again), it still shows up.

Comment: Here's another WP site I manage on the same host and the same icon shows up there for me as well: http://levnadsvanebloggen.se/
Do you guys not see the red icon with a white 5?

Comment: Well, I checked both sites and I see no icon in any of them.

Comment: Indeed (no favicon), now this might of course be the result of some plugin although on other sites like sx the favicon shows up.

Comment: I do only see it in Chrome, so I guess it's got something to do with the browser or some plugin I have installed (although I can't imagine which one it could be, I only have like three). Did anyone of you look at it in Chrome too?

Comment: Yes, no icon displayed. Extensions installed are DoNotTrackMe, DuckDuckGo and UmletGithub (so I guess this won't do any funny stuff with a favicon).

Comment: Don't see that it could be a corrupted profile since it only shows up on the sites I have on this host. Still it's super weird that no one else is seeing it. I'll solve the problem by just putting a favicon in the root, like Mark suggested below. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be just in your browsers cache. re-bookmarking the page might help...

There might also be a fallback icon defined in the server config (which you might not be able to access). see https://stackoverflow.com/a/2729435/1468708

How about you just add a favicon.ico file to the webroot?

Comment: I haven't seen the icon before and thought it was only on this site, but now I checked another site I manage on the same web host which also doesn't have a specified favicon and it shows up there too, so what you're saying about it being in the server config makes sense. Yeah, the easiest solution seems to be to just put a favicon in there.